# Is the intersection of two arbitrary subsets of a $\sigma$- Algebra a $\sigma$- Algebra over one of the subsets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak F)$ be a measure field and $Y \in \mathfrak F$.

I am trying to find out, if the set $\mathfrak L:= \{X \cap Y : X \in F \}$ spans a $\sigma$-Algebra over $Y$.

I am trying to prove these three axioms but I am already doubting that $\mathfrak L$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra, because I can't prove a).
(a) $\Omega \in \mathscr{F}$;

(b) if $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots \in \mathcal{F}$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \in \mathcal{F}$;

(c) if $A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $A^{\mathrm{c}} \in \mathcal{F}$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is only a trace $\sigma$-Algebra, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Trace_Sigma-Algebra and can never be a $\sigma$-Algebra on $\Omega$ because as you already pointed out, $\Omega$ is not contained in it as long as $Y\neq\Omega$

Comment: Why do you want to prove (a)? Wouldn't the thing like that to be shown be $Y \in \mathfrak L$ ?